# Powering Small WSP2811 Strip with 3Volts?

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, circuit-analysis, led-strip

I am a beginner when it comes to electronics and was wondering if I could get someone's help with this project. I was looking at [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01AU6UG70) led's, and was wondering if I cut them up into pieces of three LED's each, would I be able to power the three LED's to a decent brightness with [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32956232329.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.70002808qU3X8I&algo_pvid=30f7475b-9072-4343-90bd-98ca6dca161f&algo_expid=30f7475b-9072-4343-90bd-98ca6dca161f-6&btsid=0be3764315907658146716376e62bf&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_) 3V battery? I know that the ADAFRUIT website states than their led strips can be powered at lower voltages. Here's the quote:

> "Lower voltages are always acceptable, with the caveat that the LEDs
>   will be slightly dimmer." -[Reference](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/basic-connections?view=all)

I would just like to know if 3V is too low, or would this work?

EDIT: After doing more research, those Coin cells can only pull around 4mA or so, so that definitely won't work. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to power the led strip with only 3 LEDs and an ATtiny85 with the smallest possible battery (smallest in dimensions not mAh, as I want to make my project as small as possible)

Comment: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2811.pdf the datasheet for the WS2811 (what your strip is based off of) that adafruit shows is... bad. It doesn't list a minimum input voltage, nor have a Vf vs I graph. Anyway... the batteries that you posted are usually for watches and such, in other words, stuff that draws very little current. LEDs, which draw much more current, would drain those cells very quickly. When trying to run things from batteries that need a higher voltage, your options are to put the batteries in series, or use power conversion to go from 3V to your desired voltage.

Comment: Hmmm, you would think they would post a the Vf vs I graph somewhere... So I guess if the 3V won't do the trick, I could connect two of these in series and power it just fine? I could always find a coin battery with better mAh (say 620maH should power 3 20mA LED's for about 10 hours), so I'm not too worries about the battery life

Comment: A coin cell probably not, even those 620mAh ones have high internal resistances. So as you try to pull more current, the voltage drops pretty quickly. https://data.energizer.com/pdfs/lithiumcoin_appman.pdf

Comment: Yea, after doing more research, those Coin cells can only pull around 4mA or so, so that definitely won't work. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to power the led strip with 3 LEDs and an ATtiny85 with the smallest possible battery (smallest in dimensions not mAH, as I want to make my project as small as possible)